# Scenekit: Why doesn't my camera see far objects?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

This is probably a very noob question, sorry. But I tried to change every parameters of my camera in my SceneKit file to make this problem disappear but as you can see in the pictures below, as I rotate the camera, there is some kind of limit where objects disappear.

Thanks a lot if you could help

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the `zFar` value and the `automaticallyAdjustsZRange` value on the camera?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist thanks. the zFar value is 4000 but when I move it from 0 to 4000, it doesn't seem to cause any change. I didn't set any value for automaticallyAdjustsZRange though

Comment: And that camera is the `pointOfView` for the SceneKit view?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DavidRönnqvist. The only thing I had to do was setting `automaticallyAdjustsZRange` to true on my `SCNCamera` node.